# What's the advantage of using move constructor vs passing a pointer?

Tags: c++, constructor, move, move-semantics

```
Foo(Foo&& other) {
  this->bar = other.bar;
  other.bar = nullptr;
}

Foo(Foo* other) {
  this->bar = other->bar;
  other->bar = nullptr;
}
```

The above two seem to be just doing the same. So why is it recommended to use move constructor? What advantages does it provide?

Comment: Well, for starters, you can't take the address of an rvalue...

Comment: The advantages is that move constructor will be used automatically in applicable move/copy contexts. Your "pointer" constructor will not be.

Comment: Also, a reference cannot be null, but a pointer can be, so you would have to explicitly check for that condition before swapping.

Answer (score 6):

The reasons for using a proper move constructor are many:

1. Convention. Consider the following code:

   ```
   Foo foo;
   Foo bar(std::move(foo));
   ```

   If you see that code, it is *abundantly* clear what you're trying to do: you're moving `foo` into `bar`. By contrast:

   ```
   Foo foo;
   Foo bar(&foo);
   ```

   What does this mean? Is it storing a pointer to another `Foo`? Is `Foo` some sort of linked list node type? You'd have to look it up in the documentation for `Foo`'s pointer-based constructor.
2. You can't get a pointer to prvalues. `Foo bar(Foo{})` would (pre-C++17) create a prvalue temporary and then move from it into `bar` (the move could be elided pre-C++17). But you can't do this: `Foo bar(&Foo{})`.
3. You get automatic movement from things where it makes sense. C++17's generalized elision makes many of these automatic moves go away, but there are some that remain:

   ```
   Foo function()
   {
     Foo foo;
     //Do stuff
     return foo;
   }
   ```

   This will move from `foo` without having to call `std::move`. The reason is that `foo` is a local variable that is about to be destroyed. Returning it in this way means that it's perfectly reasonable to move from it into the return value.

   Your way would require explicitly writing `return &foo`. And that makes things rather difficult with `auto` return type deduction. Such a function would deduce a `Foo*`, which means you just returned a dangling pointer. Whereas if you do `return foo;`, it deduces a `Foo` prvalue, with an automatic move (that may be elided).
4. No need for `nullptr` checks. If you take a `Foo*`, it's possible that someone would pass a null pointer. Whereas with a reference, it's far more unlikely (and they'll have already invoked UB).

If we wanted move support with existing language constructs, we'd have just used a non-`const` reference to mean "move", not a pointer. By giving it its own syntax, make it clear when we're moving something and when we aren't.